# Fetch database record values in view file in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.1

I am having an array of records as a result my join query.

I want to show all entire record  in my view file. How is it possible? I am new to cakephp.

My controller function

```
function viewsurvey()
{
    $sid = $this->params['url']['sid'];
    $this->set('sid',$sid);
    $this->Survey->create();
    $this->loadModel('Question');
     $quest = $this->Question->find('all', array('joins' => array( 
    array( 
        'table' => 'surveys', 
        'alias' => 'Survey', 
        'type' => 'inner', 
        'foreignKey' => false, 
        'conditions'=> array('Survey.id = Question.survid',
            'Question.survid' => $sid) 
    )

        ))); 

        print_r($quest)

        // The record is Array ( [0] => Array ( [Question] => Array ( [id] => 9 [survid] => 2 [quest] => mnjlkj [type] => 2 [qvalues] => yes,no ) ) [1] => Array ( [Question] => Array ( [id] => 10 [survid] => 2 [quest] => mnm,n [type] => 1 [qvalues] => 0 ) ) )

}
```

I wish to fetch each row in a div in my view file; until all rows are fetched. How is it possible. Hope anyone will advice me at the earliest.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the variable `$quest` in your controller. So the data can be accessed by the `view.ctp`

```
$this->set('quest', $quest);
```

and than you can read it in you view.

```
foreach($quest as $q){
   echo '<div>'.$q['Question']['id'].'<br />
      '.$q['Question']['survid'].'<br />
      '.$q['Question']['quest'].'<br />
      '.$q['Question']['type'].'<br />
      '.$q['Question']['qvalues'].'
   </div>';  
}
```

For every record you have there will be a new div made. In your case there will be made 2 div's

**Edit after comment about looping numbers:**

```
$i=1;
foreach($quest as $q){
   ...
   ...
   $i++;
}
```

Comment: Can you give a number like 1, 2, etc for each loop? How is it possible?

Comment: How do you mean? You mean like under the edit? that it counts all the loops for you? starting with 1?